# Como eu faço para fazer um AND no PHP e eexecutar no Banco mysql

Tags: php

Eu estou fazendo um programa em *PHP* que vai precisar executar uma determinada consulta no *mysql*, não estou conseguindo.

```
SELECT * 
FROM tb_dados 
WHERE cod_uf_mun = 1100205
  AND no_curso LIKE '%vetérinaria%';
```

Não funciona por que o `AND` é uma palavra reservada do php. Como faço esse mesmo sql?

Answer (score 1):

A sua query tem que ser uma string, isso não vai conflitar com o PHP. Dê uma olhada no exemplo abaixo. Sugiro pesquisar sobre o assunto.

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT * FROM tb_dados WHERE cod_uf_mun = 1100205  AND no_curso LIKE '%vetérinaria%'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "id: " . $row["id"]. " - Name: " . $row["firstname"]. " " . $row["lastname"]. "<br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

mysqli_query($query);

Dê uma olhada neste site: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp

Comment: não funciona, tipo se eu tirar o que tem apartir do AND funciona mais quando uso o AND ou OR não funciona e não retorna nenhum erro.

Comment: Dê uma olhada neste outro tópico:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34228090/cannot-query-mysql-database-via-php

Comment: Conseguiu Maicon?

Comment: consegui usei o seu exemplo e funcionou

Comment: Marque a resposta como certa :)